# SMB from Android to Win10 - LAN drive shown, but error 0x80070035 - Path not found

Tags: windows, android, network-shares, samba, shared-folders

Motivation: To get files from Android to my PC, I have some FTP server on the Android for long already, but it is not convenient: File manager on the PC is much better.

- I have installed some SMB server, to my Android phone: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-lan-drive-samba-filesharing-server-t3790945
- When the SMB server started, the phone appears on my PC, with Win10: OK.
- But when I try to click this (just appeared) network source, in the FileExplorer, an error pops-up: Something like "0x80070035 - Path not found."
  What is going on? ..is the root cause in the phone, or in the Win10?

Or is there another solution, possibly easier?

Settings:

- port 1445, TCP
- There is no "samba.conf" file, all of the server is set from GUI of the app.
- And it is really unsure, what to set on the side of Win10..? I.e. FireWall..? I did some additional settings there to create a new rule to allow the TCP port 1445, but no effect.
- ..nor where is the root cause really: In the server (Android side), or in the Win10?
- The rights I set on the Android Samba are 77x: read/write is the purpose. To empty my mobile, to move the files manually, (through the Win10) to my NAS.
- I do not care about the user settings: Even "public" guest is enough in the moment, because it is for "LAN" only, and time connection/download/emptying. As a PoC. (In the future I might want to access the phone from my notebook even in non-home networks, but it would be another use case.)
- I did not set any "starting folder": The server URL is just the preset \\SONYF5321 or \\192.168.2.179, as the app itself suggests. Does Win10 require any folder explicitly? It does not ask for it. Also, the server FS-root "\" should be enough, as the Android app states. (without any necessity to "root" the phone OS.) I have also tried to map the LAN-source as a LAN-disk, using \\192.168.2.179\storage\emulated\0, but again the same error, after a while of waiting.

Comment: LAN drive - SAMBA Server & Client .. for Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.webrox.landrive

Comment: I have heard, that Google added some SMB app of their own, cca in 2017, but no further info from then.

Comment: The Win10 PowerShell "Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol" says true. (SMB1 False)

Comment: asked also elsewhere: https://serverfault.com/questions/1004768/smb-from-android-to-win10-error-0x80070035-path-not-found

Comment: Sure, there is a soho router between the Android, and the Win10PC. So a possible third place of cause...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are non-root on your Android device so based on Android security, the TCP port can't be 445 and Windows doesn't allow connection to any other port than 445 for SMB.
They gives you the way to handle this here :  https://tubecast.webrox.fr/landrive/portmapping2.html (need to install a port forwarder or to download the same app from Windows Store which handle the case)

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to turn the whole task upside-down, so to work on the mobile, and access the remote storage, to push the local files outside from the Android device.

(...instead of pulling them by PC, from the Android mobile, and possibly to store them yet on a third place, on a remote storage anyway.)

For this I've got an inspiration, so I use the [Cx File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cxinventor.file.explorer) app nowadays, which shown up to be more friendly than the classic-like "two-pane" [TotalCommander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) @Android: The `TC app` has some support for the file manipulations over LAN (FTP, SMB), but... It seems incomplete or limited.

The `Cx File Explorer` offers me what I've looked for, although the GUI philosophy is different than `TC`. So I got stuck to `CFE` and I can recommend it for others too.

Still: This way I am using a cell phone as an active client, which is different than what I've asked for in the original quiestion here: I asked for a PC-client, and the Android as a server. Though, my purpose to archive/remove files from the mobile is reachable, I use it regularly.